# Trying to POST Information to a Locally Created MySQL Database

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am working on a project where I need connect a MySQL database to code I have written. The structure of the database itself is going to be very simple. However, before I even approach trying to setup my planned database, I have decided to create a database that I will use temporarily just to see if I can correctly send a POST request to it. Based on my attempts, I am clearly unable to do so. I get the following error via the Firefox Inspector:

`NetworkError: A network error occurred.  shipviewer.js:38
sendAJAX file:///C:/Users/laymmi/Documents/Ship%20Viewer/shipviewer.js:38:5
updateDatabase file:///C:/Users/laymmi/Documents/Ship%20Viewer/shipviewer.js:12:2
onclick file:///C:/Users/laymmi/Documents/Ship%20Viewer/shipviewer.html:1:1`

I really do not understand the very generic network error from Firefox; which makes it difficult to diagnosis the error. However, I can reasonably discern that my issue comes from trying to send data via my POST request in shipviewer.js to the test MySQL database located on my laptop. Now whether this because I am sending data in an incorrect format, using the wrong URL (in this case it is just pointing to `localhost:3306` rather than a server located on the Internet), or a combination of the two, I do not know. My server is definitely up and running on port 3306.

Does anyone have an idea of what the issue(s) may be? I am sure it is a beginner’s mistake as I am just starting to get my feet wet regarding databases.

**shipviewer.html:**

```
 -->
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Ship Viewer v0.0.6</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shipviewer.css">

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Ship Viewer</h1>

    <!-- All software and build information regarding the ships will displayed here-->
    <div id="main">
        <div id="ship0" class="shipContainer" > 
            <div class="shipName"><h3>Name of Ship!</h3></div>
            <div class="shipHeader" >
                <span class="version">Version</span>
                <span class="build">Build</span>
            </div>
            <div class="holder flex">
                <!-- The name of the pieces of software will be on the left half of a shipContainer -->
                <div class="leftColumn flex">
                    <div class="alignRight">
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_1</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_2</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_3</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_4</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_5</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_6</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_7</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_8</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_9</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_10</p>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <!-- The version and build numbers for each piece of software will be on the right half of a shipContainer -->
                <div class="rightColumn flex">
                    <div class="versionName">
                        <div class="addMarginLeft">
                            <div id="versionName0Ship0">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName0Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName1Ship0">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName1Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName2Ship0">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName2Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName3Ship0">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName3Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName4Ship0">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName4Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName5Ship0">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName5Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName6Ship0">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName6Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName7Ship0">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName7Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName8Ship0">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName8Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName9Ship0">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName9Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="buildName">
                        <div class="addMarginLeft">
                            <div id="buildName0Ship0">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName0Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName1Ship0">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName1Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName2Ship0">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName2Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName3Ship0">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName3Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName4Ship0">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName4Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName5Ship0">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName5Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName6Ship0">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName6Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName7Ship0">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName7Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName8Ship0">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName8Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName9Ship0">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName9Ship0Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span id="returnedTestInfo" >Information...?</span>
            </div>
            <button class="mainButton" id="editButton0" onclick="toggleShipViewerInformation('editButton0', 'updateButton0', 'cancelButton0', 0)">Edit</button>
            <button class="mainButton invisible" id="updateButton0" onclick="updateDatabase('Can you see this?')">Update</button>
            <button class="mainButton invisible" id="cancelButton0" onclick="toggleShipViewerInformation('editButton0', 'updateButton0', 'cancelButton0', 0)">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        <div id="ship1" class="shipContainer" > 
        <div class="shipName"><h3>Name of Ship!</h3></div>
            <div class="shipHeader" >
                <span class="version">Version</span>
                <span class="build">Build</span>
            </div>
            <div class="holder flex">
                <!-- The name of the pieces of software will be on the left half of a shipContainer -->
                <div class="leftColumn flex">
                    <div class="alignRight">
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_1</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_2</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_3</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_4</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_5</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_6</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_7</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_8</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_9</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_10</p>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <!-- The version and build numbers for each piece of software will be on the right half of a shipContainer -->
                <div class="rightColumn flex">
                    <div class="versionName">
                        <div class="addMarginLeft">
                            <div id="versionName0Ship1">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName0Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName1Ship1">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName1Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName2Ship1">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName2Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName3Ship1">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName3Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName4Ship1">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName4Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName5Ship1">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName5Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName6Ship1">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName6Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName7Ship1">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName7Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName8Ship1">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName8Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName9Ship1">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName9Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="buildName">
                        <div class="addMarginLeft">
                            <div id="buildName0Ship1">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName0Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName1Ship1">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName1Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName2Ship1">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName2Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName3Ship1">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName3Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName4Ship1">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName4Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName5Ship1">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName5Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName6Ship1">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName6Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName7Ship1">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName7Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName8Ship1">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName8Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName9Ship1">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName9Ship1Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="mainButton" id="editButton1" onclick="toggleShipViewerInformation('editButton1', 'updateButton1', 'cancelButton1', 1)">Edit</button>
            <button class="mainButton invisible" id="updateButton1">Update</button>
            <button class="mainButton invisible" id="cancelButton1" onclick="toggleShipViewerInformation('editButton1', 'updateButton1', 'cancelButton1', 1)">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        <div id="ship2" class="shipContainer" > 
        <div class="shipName"><h3>Name of Ship!</h3></div>
            <div class="shipHeader" >
                <span class="version">Version</span>
                <span class="build">Build</span>
            </div>
            <div class="holder flex">
                <!-- The name of the pieces of software will be on the left half of a shipContainer -->
                <div class="leftColumn flex">
                    <div class="alignRight">
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_1</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_2</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_3</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_4</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_5</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_6</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_7</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_8</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_9</p>
                        <p class="columnFormatting">INFO_10</p>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <!-- The version and build numbers for each piece of software will be on the right half of a shipContainer -->
                <div class="rightColumn flex">
                    <div class="versionName">
                        <div class="addMarginLeft">
                            <div id="versionName0Ship2">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName0Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName1Ship2">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName1Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName2Ship2">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName2Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName3Ship2">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName3Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName4Ship2">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName4Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName5Ship2">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName5Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName6Ship2">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName6Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName7Ship2">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName7Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName8Ship2">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName8Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                            <div id="versionName9Ship2">50.87.1</div> <input type="text" id="versionName9Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="10" size="10" value="test...">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="buildName">
                        <div class="addMarginLeft">
                            <div id="buildName0Ship2">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName0Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName1Ship2">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName1Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName2Ship2">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName2Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName3Ship2">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName3Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName4Ship2">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName4Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName5Ship2">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName5Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName6Ship2">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName6Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName7Ship2">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName7Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName8Ship2">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName8Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                            <div id="buildName9Ship2">1204</div> <input type="text" id="buildName9Ship2Textbox" class="invisible" maxlength="4" size="4" value="test">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="mainButton" id="editButton2" onclick="toggleShipViewerInformation('editButton2', 'updateButton2', 'cancelButton2', 2)">Edit</button>
            <button class="mainButton invisible" id="updateButton2">Update</button>
            <button class="mainButton invisible" id="cancelButton2" onclick="toggleShipViewerInformation('editButton2', 'updateButton2', 'cancelButton2', 2)">Cancel</button>
        </div>



    </div>
    <script src="shipviewer.js"></script>
</body>
<footer>

</footer>

</html>
```

**shipviewer.js:**

```
/*********************************************************************************************************************
This function will POST user given information to the database; thereby updating it.
Parameters:
    url - the server (file) location
    data - the information being sent/requested
*********************************************************************************************************************/
function updateDatabase(data){
    var url = "localhost:3306";                                 //the URL for sending info?
    sendAJAX("POST", url, data);
}

/*********************************************************************************************************************
This function sends AJAX requests
Parameters:
    requestType - a string that is a SQL request type (GET, POST, etc.)
    url - the server (file) location
    data - the information being sent/requested
*********************************************************************************************************************/
function sendAJAX(requestType, url, data) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();                             //XMLHttpRequest object is required for AJAX requests
    // req.addEventListener('error', function(err) {
    //    alert(err.message);
    //}, false);

    req.open(requestType, url, true);                           //Initializes the asynchronous request

    req.onreadystatechange = function() {                       //Defines a function to be called when the readyState property changes
        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {      //XMLHttpRequest code 4 == request finished and response is ready; HTTP status code 200 == OK 
            document.getElementById("returnedTestInfo").innerHTML = this.responseText;      //Returns the response data (from the server) as a string
        }//else if(this.readyState === 4) {                     //request finished and response is ready, but some error has occurred
            //alert(this.responseText);
        //}
    };

    req.send(data);                                             //Sends the request
}
/*
function sendAJAX(requestType, url, data, contentType,onSuccess) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();                             //XMLHttpRequest object is required for AJAX requests
    req.addEventListener('error', function(err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }, false);

    req.open(requestType, url);                                 //Initializes the request

    req.onreadystatechange = function() {                       //Defines a function to be called when the readyState property changes
        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {      //XMLHttpRequest code 4 == request finished and response is ready; HTTP status code 200 == OK 
            onSuccess(this.responseText);                       //Returns the response data (from the server) as a string
        } else if(this.readyState === 4) {
            alert(this.responseText);
        }
    };

    if(contentType) {
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", contentType);
    }
    req.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    req.send(data);                                             //Sends the request
}
*/
//req.open("POST", the_server_(file)_location, true);
//req.send(); 

/*********************************************************************************************************************
This function toggles between displaying information and allowing the user to edit the information via the Edit or 
Cancel buttons.
Parameters:
    elementIdEdit - element ID of the Edit button
    elementIdUpdate - element ID of the Update button
    elementIdCancel - element ID of the Cancel button
    shipNum - an int that corresponds to a particular ship. Ex: "ship0" == 0  
*********************************************************************************************************************/
function toggleShipViewerInformation(elementIdEdit, elementIdUpdate, elementIdCancel, shipNum){
    var versionName = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"];
    var buildName = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"];
    var versionNameTextbox = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"];
    var buildNameTextbox = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"];

    //Assigning the vars in the array with element DOM information.
    for(var count = 0; count < versionName.length; count++){
        versionName[count] = document.getElementById("versionName"+count+"Ship"+shipNum);
        buildName[count] = document.getElementById("buildName"+count+"Ship"+shipNum);
        versionNameTextbox[count] = document.getElementById("versionName"+count+"Ship"+shipNum+"Textbox");
        buildNameTextbox[count] = document.getElementById("buildName"+count+"Ship"+shipNum+"Textbox");
    }

    //Toggling the version and build information from read-only text to editable textboxes
    for(var count = 0; count < versionName.length; count++){
        toggleClass(versionName[count], "invisible");
        toggleClass(buildName[count], "invisible");
        toggleClass(versionNameTextbox[count], "invisible");
        toggleClass(buildNameTextbox[count], "invisible");
    }

    toggleButtons(elementIdEdit, elementIdUpdate, elementIdCancel);
}
/*********************************************************************************************************************
This function calls toggleClass() to show/hide the appropriate set of buttons when the user clicks on Edit or Cancel
*********************************************************************************************************************/
function toggleButtons(elementIdEdit, elementIdUpdate, elementIdCancel) {
    var edit = document.getElementById(elementIdEdit);
    var update = document.getElementById(elementIdUpdate);
    var cancel = document.getElementById(elementIdCancel);

    //Hiding/Showing the Edit button
    toggleClass(edit, "invisible");

    //Showing/Hiding the Update and Cancel buttons
    toggleClass(update, "invisible");
    toggleClass(cancel, "invisible");
}

/*********************************************************************************************************************
This function toggles whatever class is passed as a parameter. Example: the invisible class which is placed or removed
on the buttons. 
*********************************************************************************************************************/
function toggleClass(element, className) {

    if(element.classList.contains(className)) {
        element.classList.remove(className);
    } else {
        element.classList.add(className);
    }
}
```

**shipviewer.css:**

```
/*
header{
    background-color: #F9F0D7;
    color: #A3916A;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;


}
*/
body { 
    background-color: white; 
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    /*font-weight: 400;*/
    /*background: linear-gradient(#27A7DE, #19173C) fixed;*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
} 
footer { 
    background-color: #272562;      /* imperial purple */
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;

    /*display: flex;*/
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.shipContainer {
    background-color: #272562;      /* imperial purple */
    color: white;
    width: 33%;
    height: 600px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.shareContainer {
    width: 33%;
    /*align-content: flex-start;*/
    margin: 0px;
}

.softwareName {
    text-align: right;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
}

.marginForDisplay {
    margin: 10px;
}

.alignRight {
    text-align: right;
}

.addMarginLeft {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.invisible {
        display: none;
}

.shipHeader {
    text-align: center;
}   

.version {
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.build {
    //margin-right: 80px;
}

.leftColumn {
    /*max-width: 150px;*/
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.columnFormatting {
    margin: 0px;
    min-width: 95px;
}

#listOfInfo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I haven't worked with AJAX, so I can't be sure, but I've never seen XML (or http requests of any sort) sent directly/explicitly to a database. Typically, a SQL query is sent (unless some sort of API that semi-hides the database is used).

Comment: can you post your PHP to process the data?

Comment: @Uueerdo, can you state what you would normally expect to see SQL/JavaScript wise? Some sort of `SELECT * FROM testDatabase;' statement?

@Jonny so this may be a really dumb question. But why would I need any PHP code? PHP, as far as I understand it, is code that runs server-side. So if a user is only going to be sending and receiving data from the database via requests, the database wouldn’t need to do any on its own.

Comment: @lordmichael95 Yes, I'd expect to see "SELECT * FROM ...", "INSERT INTO sometable....", etc... I haven't done much web programming, but it seems to me that if you're using client side scripting every client will need a direct connection to your database, or send their information to something server side that has a connection to the database. (but like I said, I'm not really familiar with AJAX or web programming in general, so I wouldn't take my word as gospel.